# react app express server CORS request did not succeed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors

I am trying to connect my front end to my back end, and I am using express server with node and react.

this is my fetch request fom front end: server runs on port 5000

```
const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/send-email", {
  to_email: data.data.email,
  url: data.data.url,
});

console.log(response);
```

this resutls in:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/send-email. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

I have  in my back end:

```
app.post("/send-email", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { to_email, url } = req.body;
    console.log(to_email, url);
    await sendMail()
      .then((result) => console.log("Email sent...", result))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));

    res.send({ express: "YOUR EXPRESS BACKEND IS CONNECTED TO REACT" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: error });
  }
});
```

I am also using core and  also something like this:

```
// app.use(function (req, res, next) {
//   // res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
//   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");

//   res.header(
//     "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
//     "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
//   );
//   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS");
//   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);

//   next();
// });
```

but regards less I keep getting this error and I am not sure how to get rid of it. I have seen several solutions they are either old, and I have tried some of them, they dont work at all.

Comment: Why is the code "something like this" all commented-out?

Comment: well, since that didnt do anything i just commented it out, it doesnt help at all!

Comment: Did you use cors library on your server?

const cors = require('cors');
app.use(
    cors({
        origin: '*',
        methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,COPY',
        preflightContinue: false,
        optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
    })
);

Comment: Yes I do like this: const cors = require("cors"); and app.use(cors());

Comment: You can fill the axios.post's third parameter with a header.
axios.post(URL, data, headers)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Answer (score 0):

1. Install cors using (`npm install cors`).
2. In your backend code file, add

   ```js
   var cors = require('cors') <br />
   app.use(cors())
   ```

Alternatively, follow instructions given at https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors.

Comment: I already have cors and yet this happens!

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it like the following:
in my front end, I have

```
const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:8000/signup", {
          newUserNameEmail,
          url,
        });

        console.log("response--> ", response.data);
```

and in my backend server:

```
const PORT = 8000;
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const { google } = require("googleapis");


const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

//sign up
app.post("/signup", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { newUserNameEmail, url } = req.body;

    console.log(newUserNameEmail, url);

    await sendMail(newUserNameEmail, url)
      .then((result) => console.log("Email sent...", result))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));

    res.status(200).json({ newUserNameEmail, url });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: error });
  }
});
```

So for some reason, this works and doesn't generate the error I was getting before. I can now communicate with front end and backend and send data, and email.

But I have no idea why this worked and the other one didnt. I also didnt change my package.json

Answer (score -2):

Add proxy in your package.json file to the port of your backend api

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8000"
```

then change your url in the request to port 3000 or wherever your frontend is

```
const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/send-email", { 
  to_email: data.data.email,
  url: data.data.url,
});

console.log(response);
```

proxy only works in local, however your app and api usually share the same main domain so this cors error will not appear in production..